# What does Lord Rama wear?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas

As Vishnu & Krishna idols or pics are shown wearing makarkundal, kaustubh gem, Srivatsalanchhan & such things. What is the right attire of Lord Rama as told in Texts to be shown wearing? At least when creating a pic/idol or decorating one. What are the essential pieces of jewelry, ornaments, clothes & marks He wears? Does He wear kanthi mala in neck? What does Lord Rama Archa Vigraha must wear?

Comment: These are known by the dhyana-slokas.There are different dhyana-slokas of Sri Rama. You could check : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34373/what-is-the-source-of-ramachandra-having-a-green-colored-form/34374#34374

Comment: And no Vigraha of God ever wears Kanthi-Mala. Kanthi-Mala is used by the Gaudiya Vaishnavas.God is NOT a Gaudiya Vaishnava!!

Comment: Related question and answer [What did the royal families wear during Ramayana and Mahabharata era?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21761/5212)

Comment: OK thank u so much :D :D @commonman

Comment: Yes sarvabhuma sir.. I checked out that question :)